# LD_LIBRARY_PATH precendence and trouble with compiling

Tags: python, linux, r, rpy2, installation

I am trying to install some software on a Linux machine (python's rpy2 package, rpy2.robjects in particular, if it matters).  I need the software to look for its shared libraries in my local space, not in the global spaces like /usr/lib64 whatever.  I do not have admin privileges on this machine.  My problem is that even though I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to my local space, the software still goes to the /usr/lib64/whatever, where it finds libraries that are out of date.  These libraries are missing some objects it needs, so it fails.  What could be taking precedence over LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and is there a way to change/get rid of it?  Thanks.

BTW, someone on this site had a similar question a year or more ago, but his answer involved the env variable RPATH, and changing it with the chrpath utility.  It is not clear to me at all that rpy2 is using RPATH, and chrpath seems unavailable on my system.

Addendum:  I tried running with LD_DEBUG=libs.  Got alot of output that looks like the system is looking for the libs in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH and finding them.  Here is where the trouble seems to start:

```
/usr/local/lib64/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so: error: symbol lookup error:
undefined symbol: Rf_allocS4Object (fatal)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib64/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so':
/usr/local/lib64/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so: undefined symbol: Rf_allocS4Object
```

So my guess is that the trouble is that whatever is in DLLpath is overriding LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I have tried to change this by prepending my directories to os.environ['PATH'], but no do.  There is apparently no "DLLPATH", as I thought there would be.

OK, that's progress, I guess.  Anybody have anything else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still reading this, I engaged in some "personnel engineering" to solve the problem, i.e. got the system admins to re-install R so that it had everything I needed.  Was certainly nice of them.  Thanks very much to everyone who gave suggestions.  Would like to keep going on some of them, but I've got to get busy on this project.  Much obliged!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at a file named $R_HOME/etc/ldpaths (where in your case $R_HOME seems to be /usr/local/lib64/R). It is the commands in this file that set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at R's start-up.

Mine looks like this:

```
flodel@netbook-samsung-N150:~$ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths 
: ${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre}
: ${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/i386/client:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni}
if test -n ""; then
: ${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${R_HOME}/lib:}
else
: ${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${R_HOME}/lib}
fi
if test -n "${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"; then
  R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
fi
if test -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"; then
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
else
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If you do not have write access to the file, you can still do this before starting R:

```
export R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/custom/path
```

I tested on my machine that it works by running the following after R is started:

```
Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
#[1] "/your/custom/path:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni"
```

Comment: Have to go and have to be away from the desk for a couple of days, so can't try anything else right now.  But thanks to everybody for your help!

Comment: flodel, if you or anyone is still reading here, I tried  setting R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  It seemed to work in setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but the behavior I get when I try to get to R through rpy2 is still the same as above.  python/rpy2 just won't stip heading for the old libraries.  Any other thoughts are most welcome.  BTW, to look at the value of "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", I had to use os.getenv(), not Sys.getenv().  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`RPATH` is only useful when compiling (well, linking); it affects the library search path that gets baked into the binary.

Try running with `LD_DEBUG=libs`, which will show libraries are being loaded from which paths.  Is it trying to load from your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but failing, or not searching there in the first place (perhaps `rpy2` has its own library path mechanism?), or something else?

Comment: No-no, RPATH is useful when running, too.

Comment: @VladLazarenko How so?  `man ld.so` documents its runtime library search path, which is: `DT_RPATH` in the binary, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the environment, `DT_RUNPATH` in the binary, in the `ld.so.cache` (normally built based on `ld.so.conf`), and in the standard library locations.  `RPATH` in the environment is not used.

Comment: OK, I tried LD_DEBUG.  A very useful tool that I was not aware of.  Here is a snippet of output:

Comment: OK, if you don't mind, I will put the output into an edit of my question.  It is unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your directory on the left of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the precedence goes left to right.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/your/custom/path:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks much, but I'm still getting the same problem.