# Path To libstdc++ while installing R package

Tags: r, gcc, libstdc++

So I've been trying to install an R package called `igraph`. At the end when it tries to load the package, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /tools/R/2.15.2/lib64/R/library/igraph/libs/igraph.so)
```

To me this error means that there's the wrong version of `libstdc++.so.6`. I, however am not using that file. A quick look to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/tools/gcc/4.7.0/lib64
```

In that directory there is a file named libstdc++.so.6 and the following shows that GLIBCXX_3.4.15 is actually there:

```
strings /tools/gcc/4.7.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I don't understand why R is being stubborn and not using the file under the gcc directory and keeps trying to reference the /user/lib64 directory. Does anyone any have ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out there's a file under: `$RHOME/etc/` called `ldpaths` that clears the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for some reason.  I reset the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to my preferred paths in that file, relaunched R, and the package installed quite smoothly.

On a side-node: I think this is ridiculous behaviour for such a mature piece of software.

Comment: This sounds like it's specific to your environment.

Comment: It does not clear it: it prepends to it the directories that were used when you compiled R.
You apparently changed something on your system between the moment you installed R
and the moment you installed igraph. Expect other things to break...

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658687/ld-library-path-precendence-and-trouble-with-compiling